Running React on port 80 but still want access to PhpMyAdmin
I have an Ubuntu server with a LAMP stack already but recently added a react server aswell. My web domain points to port 80 of course which is the apache server but I would like to have it go to my react app. I could turn off apache and set react to use port 80, but then I loose access to phpymyadmin aswell? Not sure what the best way of doing this is. Need help.
I tried changing react to use port 80 in package.json but it complained saying i need administrator access but even when I try “sudo npm start” it doesnt work. I also tried making my domain just point to port 3000 but that didnt work. I also tried just making my apache html file redirect to my react app but then it exposes my IP address instead of the domain being in the search bar.
